# Force Swift Playgrounds (xcode) to Use MacOS SpriteKit without Simulating iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift-playground, wwdc

I've been working on a Swift Playgrounds project in xcode for the past week as a WWDC scholarship submission. I'm almost done, but I couldn't seem to figure out why the project was running with such a low framerate. However, in this scholarship submission (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pe4V74afBS8), the playground appeared to run perfectly fine. In the comments section of the video, the creator stated that, "It's the default 60 fps, be sure to use the macOS SpriteKit instead of the iOS simulated SpriteKit, that way your performance will be much better." How would one achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

When you try to create a playground (option shift command N), Xcode will ask you what OS the playground will run on:

[image]

[image]

Note the different tabs on the top.

If you want a macOS playground, click on the macOS tab select the "Game" template.